# Measure distance with iPhone 7

Tags: ios, swift

Is there a camera API on iOS that can gives us the distance to the object?

iPhone 7 gots 2 cameras and it is possible to blur background automatically.

I suppose iOS can calculate distance, but is there a way to get this distance from an application?

Comment: I don't know it it's possible, and there's no api that I know of to do it easily. None the less, here are two similar threads to get you started. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8698889/how-to-measure-height-width-and-distance-of-object-using-camera
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22634518/how-to-get-distance-of-object-from-iphone-camera-using-image-exif-meta-data